# Create PackageMaker project file on the command line

Tags: scripting, automation, packagemaker

Is there any way of creating a pmdoc (PackageMaker) project from the command line?

I am trying to automate the process of creating the installer and would like to script tasks like:

1. Adding another application
2. Updating the installer project when the apps it contains change.

My question is: Is there a command line tool I can use to construct a packagemaker project on the command line?

For example: `packagemaker` will build an installer from a .pmdoc folder structure.

What can I use to create the .pmdoc folder structure from the command line?

Comment: Just FYI: it seems they're phasing `packagemaker` out. You might want to consider using pkgbuild: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command-line tool to generate .pmdoc files. PackageMakers [--root](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/packagemaker.1.html) option allows you to generate packages. The other parameter of --root allow you to set stuff like the title, package identifier and so on.

As Pooria Azimia already commented, PackageMaker is deprecated. From own experience I can only recommend to [use the new tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re?lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so such tool is available. I explored the options and then come up with the solution:

I have created a .pmdoc file and then ran the command as below:

> PackageMaker --doc "your.pmdoc" --version buildnumber --title
>   "Installer.pkg" --out "/Desktop/Installer1.pkg"

Command will create an installer. However, I won't be able to modify the installer version in this solution. Actually, I was looking for the command to change the content of .pmdoc but didn't find anything yet.