# Running PackageMaker from command line

Tags: macos, packagemaker, pkg-file

I have a `.pmdoc` file I want to generate a `.pkg` from.
I have to do it from command line since its an automatic tool.

I looked at questions such as [Create PackageMaker project file on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149169/create-packagemaker-project-file-on-the-command-line), but I can't find `packagemaker` command anywhere.

Seems like it should be in `/Developer/usr/bin/packagemaker` ?

In any case, I have `PackageMaker.app` installed, so the GUI works fine, but where can I find the command line util?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently its simpler than I thought:

`/Applications/PackageMaker.app/Contents/MacOs/PackageMaker`

Answer (score 1):

/Applications/PackageMaker.app/Contents/MacOs/PackageMaker --doc "your.pmdoc" --version BuildVersion --title "Title" --out "/Users/username/Desktop/Installer.pkg"

Answer (score -1):

PackageMaker --doc "your.pmdoc" --version buildnumber --title "Test.pkg" --out "/Desktop/Test.pkg"